# Schedule Task with Jax-RS and CDI

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs, cdi

I'm try to understand how to manage scheduled tasks in my project with Jax-RS and CDI.
With Spring I was easily able to achive that with `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` or  `@Scheduled` annotation and I'm trying to replicate both ways without success.

First of all, I'm using Wildfly 14 and this seems to cause some issues because I've tryied to inject with `@Resource` both `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` and `TimerService` but Wildfly throws exception of missing dependencies (but the Admin guide didn't help me about that).

Instead of inject resources I've tryied to use a singleton object like this:

```
@Singleton
public class CacheManager {
    private final static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public CacheManager() {
         log.error("######## Init" + LocalTime.now());
    }

     @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/1")
     private void timeout() {
         log.error("######## " + LocalTime.now());
     }

}
```

But the method is never called.

So I'm not understanding what I'm missing. Maybe I have wrongly configured the project so this is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is my beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

I am using Java 8.

EDIT: the CacheManager is instantiated in the JAX-WS Application

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private HashSet<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public JaxRsActivator() {
        singletons.add(new CorsFilter());
        singletons.add(new CacheManager());      
    }   

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

    @Override
    public HashSet<Class<?>> getClasses(){
      return classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get it to work with a plain servlet? or  plain jsp? Or a jax-ws? Or JSF? Or even a unit test? With 99% certainty this is not jax-rs related.

Comment: Jax-ws which works correctly.

Comment: That is not what I mean. By stating it does not work with jax-rs you sort of implicitly state you have no problem when you want to start it via a servlet or something else. There is effectively nothing in your question jax-rs related. Create a servlet, does it work there? If not, your problem is more generic and you can search for more generic solutions/problems.

Comment: Ok, now there is, but you do a 'new' of the CacheManager... Then it is not a managed instance, managed by a container like CDI or whatever. Effectively you'd have the same problem in a unittest or a servlet or... At least that is what I think. I use jax-rs, but use the `Application` extended class only for pure jax-rs things. Other **real** application scoped things are in generic `@ApplicationScoped` things. So I'm not sure if you are trying to use something JaxRS specific but design wise, I'd not do it like this

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've removed the CacheManager from the Jax-rs initializator and I put a @Startup annotation on CacheManager so now starts with the application on it's own.

Comment: That is why I stated to try with other front-end frameworks or a unittest... they would most likely have failed to... Narrowing down the issue is always a good thing to do. Now you were most likely searching to specifically in a search engine and found nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solutions: @Singleton must be javax.ejb.Singleton and not javax.inject.Singleton.

Comment: And the instantiation in jax-rs is then completely superfluous...I'd think